# How to force Excel chart to skip 0 without using NA()? or return "empty" by IF

Tags: excel, charts, spreadsheet

I am struggling with known issue in Excel.
I have chart prepared for upcoming years.
I am using trend lines in this chart to see projected value.
As table is being filled every month, major part of the cells with results (calculated sums, avg's etc) are empty as based on 0, but as you know - it's impossible to return empty cell.

When I return 0, "" - I have issue with chart - these not filled cells are shown as 0 on chart, so I get crap trend.
When I return NA() - chart is working fine but I get crap average (I calculate averageif, so in all empty lines I have value from last filled line.

I realize it is quite complicated to explain, but maybe someone know solution.
I was digging a lot and tried lot of solutions, but nothing works to solve both issues.

Comment: Can you upload a picture?   What do you mean by returning `0,""`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, the question your asking is what I often face too.  Here are some of my tricks:

## - Use conditions in the average -

Leave the invalid data as NA().  instead of using `averageif(...)`, in the the average put a condition on the source data like `average( if( isnumber(A20:A40), A20:A40, "" ) )`, and press **ctrl-shift-enter** to complete the formula as an array.  You must use **ctrl-shift-enter**, it will not work as a normal formula!

## - Use a filter -

Leave the invalid data as "". Use the `Filter` feature to remove the data. Enable the filter (see below) and remove the invalid points (see also below), by default the graph will not plot the data you filter out.

#### Enable the filter

see the `DATA` menu, in the `Sort&Filter` section, click `Filter`.  It will guess about your table size, but if you select the whole table first it forces the filter to be what you want)

#### Apply the filter

You'll see buttons on each of your header columns, click the one on a column that you can use to remove the data you don't want (i.e., uncheck blank).

Comment: Cool! Filter messed up chart, but I choose `average( if( isnumber(A20:A40), A20:A40, "" ) )` and it works good! I enter it by myself with my ranges but solution is great. Thank you!

Comment: By default the charts have their position locked to the cells.  When you filter the cells move and the chart often get squished.  To fix this go into the chart size properties and choose "Do not move or size with cells".